# If I try to install any of 5.8.* new kernels, an error shows up: "ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.8.*-generic is not supported"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, virtualbox, dkms

I'm in PopOS. If I try to install any of 5.8.* new kernels, an error shows up: "ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.8.*-generic is not supported". I have this problem with ALL the 5.8.* versions, and I can't use Virtualbox with these versions of kernels. How could I fix?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need minimum [version 6.1.14](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1762972.html) of VirtualBox to run on Kernel 5.8

> you are right thanks. if I may ask you... how did you find this? what did you search on google? in general, if I encouter a bug, what can I do in order to find news by myself instead of asking here?

In my case it was experience, I already seen reports of people where virtual box didn't run after the kernel 5.8 release few weeks ago
Actually this isn't the first time, "out-of-tree"/external kernel modules like Virtual Box or VMWare break constantly with bigger kernel changes but their developer are really slow on pushing updates to fix that

Anyway I found the informations about it after searching either "virtualbox kernel 5.8" or "virtualbox-dkms kernel 5.8" (here is the bug report from above) on DuckDuckGo

Comment: you are right thanks. if I may ask you... how did you find this? what did you search on google? in general, if I encouter a bug, what can I do in order to find news by myself instead of asking here?